# configuring p4 on red hat enterprise linux

Tags: command-line, bash, redhat-enterprise-linux, perforce

It's time to get rid of this simple but yet not easily explained topic. And whatever I got on internet, in one or other way, failed to sync my WINDOWS depot to RHEL client. Following is the stuff I have done:

1. Downloaded p4 for RHEL and stored it in /usr/local/bin
2. Edited /bashrc and made entries for P4USER=ABC, P4PORT
3. When I run the command **p4 client** it gives me error that **user ABC doesn't exists**

I wanted to know which Environment variables to be set. and why perforce guys messed it up with too much information? There must be an easy way for command line installation of p4 for RHEL.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you create the user `ABC`?

Comment: yes and I have saved environment variable also as shown above

Comment: Did you do it with something like `p4 user -f ABC`?

Comment: hey I done that

Comment: guys I got the solution. I will post it by the evening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some steps which I followed
 **NOTE**: I was logged in as normal user and not the root and it is recommended that you should not use root user for such task:

1. Read the link carefully (it does help at the very end when I figure out the answer in my way) http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/p4guide/chapter.install.html There is a download link from where you can download appropriate version of p4 for your Linux. Make sure you put this downloaded p4-binary in system path like **/usr/bin/**/ or **/usr/sbin/** etc. Make this binary executable by using **chmod** command.
2. Run the command **p4** it will then ask for **p4 trust**.Then run p4 trust and type yes to continue.
3. On command line firstly edit the **~/.bashrc** file and export the **P4PORT** and **P4USER** environment variables needed by p4.(You can find some other environment variables in above link but these two are mandatory).
4. Check if entries done perfectly by running **p4 set**. If  everything is fine then run the command **p4 login -p**, it will ask you to enter password for perforce and return a token as feedback. Just copy the token and make another export entry for **P4TOKEN** environment variable in **~/.bashrc**.
5. Run the command **p4 client** and edit the view as per requirement(as per depot access). (Escape + Shift+ ; + wq to save the changes).
6. Run **p4 sync** and all files will be synced lovaly.

If any problem occurred comment here.
Regards,